# ActivatedRoute.params.subscribe called twice

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, observable

I need to get URL parameters, so in the `ngOnInit()` I have the following part:

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params);

    // some real code
});
```

However, when I access the page (for example `localhost:8100/?foo=bar&bar=baz`), first I get empty object (`{}`) and only later I get real values (eg. `{"foo": "bar", "bar": "baz"}`). Is there any way to get rid of it?

Comment: Try this `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get(<key>);`

Comment: I tried and got empty object again.

Comment: please past your url in commit

Comment: this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        let date = params['startdate'];
        console.log(date); // Print the parameter to the console. 
    });

Comment: this way on `localhost:8100?startdate=2020-08-13` I get `undefined` and immediately after I get `2020-08-13` (line number in the log is the same)

Comment: `this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.pipe(filter(query => query.keys.length > 0)).subscribe(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

add a .pipe(filter()) before the subscribe to make sure that only the object with the real values continues onto the subscribe callback

```
this.activatedRoute.queryParams
    .pipe(filter((p: any) => p.foo && p.bar)) //type check the incoming value
    .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);

        // some real code
    });
```